# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'njtestagt' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling with few days with the issue.

I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
Declare @DbName varchar (50)
Declare @AgencyID varchar(50)

set @DbName='UPC_qat_NewBusiness'
set @AgencyID='1234568'

SET @Query = N'DELETE FROM ' + @DbName + '.dbo.PMSPAG00 WHERE AGNMMCO IN (select MasterCompanyId from ISLocation isLoc join ISAgencyLocation IsAg on IsAg.LocationIndexNbr=isLoc.LocationIndexNbr where AgencyId='+@AgencyID+') and AGNMNBR='+@AgencyID
Execute(@Query)
```

Why I am getting this error :

```
  "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'njtestagt' to data type int"
```

There is nothing in it or that value in the database records.
Please help me anyone.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As a debug step, print the value of `@Query` and see if that is the query you thought it was. Note that when you compare a column to an integer value, all values in the column are converted to int.

Comment: Since you don't have that particular value in your query then I can guarantee you that the value is present in your tables. You simply need to go hunting for it. Check all the tables involved and all the columns involved. Also, print out the query to ensure you got the right query executing.

Answer (score 3):

Change the set statement of `agencyid`

```
set @AgencyID='''1234568'''
```

or

```
SET @DbName='UPC_qat_NewBusiness'
SET @AgencyID='1234568'
SET @Query = N'DELETE FROM ' + @DbName
             + '.dbo.PMSPAG00 WHERE AGNMMCO IN (select MasterCompanyId from ISLocation isLoc 
join ISAgencyLocation IsAg on IsAg.LocationIndexNbr=isLoc.LocationIndexNbr    
 where AgencyId='''+ @AgencyID + ''') and AGNMNBR=''' + @AgencyID+ '''' --here
```

Since the `Agencyid` is a `varchar` column the values passed to that column should be enclosed with `single quotes`.

**Note :** Use `print` statement to debug the `dynamic query`